# How to know the alpha or critical value of your t test analysis?

Tags: python-3.x, scipy

How do you decide the critical values(alpha) and analyze with the p value

example: `stats.ttest_ind(early['assignment1_grade'], late['assignment1_grade'])`
(2 series with score of their assignments)

I understand the concept that if the p value is greater than the alpha value then the null hypothesis cant be neglected.
Im doing a course and instructor said that the alpha value here is 0.05 but how do you determine it.

Answer (score 0):

The alpha value cannot be determined in the sense that there were a formula to calculate it. Instead, it is arbitrarily chosen, ideally before the study is conducted.

The value alpha = 0.05 is a common choice that goes back to a suggestion by Ronald Fisher in his influential book *Statistical Methods for Research Workers* (first published in 1925). The only particular reason for this value is that if the test statistic has a normal distribution under the null hypothesis, then for a two-tailed test with alpha = 0.05 the critical values of the test statistic will be its mean plus/minus 2 (more exactly, 1.96) times its standard deviation.

In fact, you don't need alpha when you calculate the p value, because you can just publish the p value and then every reader can decide whether to consider it low enough for any given purpose or not.